# Functional TypeScript and generics

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I have created a functional TypeScript solution for a code exercise, based on a Haskell solution for that same exercise.
The exercise is to take a very large integer and finding the largest product of a group of adjacent digits of length n.

I wrote a curried function `groups` that takes an array of numbers and returns an array of arrays, with each nested array consisting of a number of digits.

For example:

```
groups([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])(3)
```

will return:

```
[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

The `groups` function:

```
type groups = <A>(xs: A[]) => (n: number) => A[][];
const groups: groups = xs => n => xs.length < n ? [] : [take(n)(xs)].concat(groups(drop(1)(xs))(n)); 

// groups uses the functions 'take' and 'drop':

type take = <A>(n: number) => (xs: A[]) => A[];
const take: take = n => xs => xs.slice(0, n);

type drop = <A>(n: number) => (xs: A[]) => A[];
const drop: drop = n => xs => xs.slice(n);
```

But `groups` gives the error:

```
TS2322: Type '{}[][]' is not assignable to type 'A[][]'.
```

However when I add `as []` the error goes away:

```
const groups: groups = xs => n => xs.length < n ? [] : [take(n)(xs)].concat(groups(drop(1)(xs))(n)) as [];
```

My first question is: why is that?

I stated the return type of `groups` is `A[][]` and the argument `xs` is of type `A[]` so why is this parsed as `{}[][]`?
I don't fully understand how this works.

Then when I run the final solution with Quokka in Webstorm I get the correct answer but another error.

First, the final solution:

```
const largestProduct = (count: number): number[] => {
  const num = '73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934969835203127745063262395';
  const digits = num.split('').map((x: string) => parseInt(x, 10));

  return Math.max(...map(product)(groups(digits)(count)));
};

// the functions 'map' and 'product' used:

type map = <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (xs: A[]) => B[];
const map: map = f => xs => xs.map(f);

type product = (xs: number[]) => number;
const product: product = xs => xs.reduce((acc, x) => acc * x, 1);
```

The line with the `return` statement gives the error:

```
TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'
```

The `map` function indeed returns `number[]` but I use the spread operator  here. For example `Math.max(...[1,2,3])` does not give this error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Math.max` returns `number`, not `number[]`, so I don't see how `largestProduct` should type-check.

Comment: I can not believe I missed that, thanx! That's already one question answered ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `take` and `drop` functions have the type parameter `A` on the outer function, while the inference site for this parameter (in the form of the `xs` parameter) is on the inner function. Typescript can't really handle this, it wants to determine all type arguments when it checks the first call (for example `take(1)`) and since it has nowhere to infer `A` from it just infers it  to `{}` leading to your problems.

The simplest solution is to move the type parameter on the inner function:

```
type groups = <A>(xs: A[]) => (n: number) => A[][];
const groups: groups = xs => n => xs.length < n ? [] : [take(n)(xs)].concat(groups(drop(1)(xs))(n)); 

type take = (n: number) => <A>(xs: A[]) => A[];
const take: take = n => xs => xs.slice(0, n);

type drop = (n: number) => <A>(xs: A[]) => A[];
const drop: drop = n => xs => xs.slice(n);
```

Just as a side not I am not 100% sold on your approach of defining the function type before. You can fully annotate an arrow function (including return type):

```
const groups = <A>(xs: A[]) => (n: number) : A[][] => xs.length < n ? [] : [take(n)(xs)].concat(groups(drop(1)(xs))(n)); 

const take = (n: number) => <A>(xs: A[]) : A[]=> xs.slice(0, n);

const drop = (n: number) => <A>(xs: A[]): A[] => xs.slice(n);
```

Although in this case the return type is not strictly necessary for `take` and `drop` and can be inferred based on return type (it is necessary for `group` because of the recursive nature of the function)

```
const groups = <A>(xs: A[]) => (n: number) : A[][] => xs.length < n ? [] : [take(n)(xs)].concat(groups(drop(1)(xs))(n)); 

const take = (n: number) => <A>(xs: A[]) => xs.slice(0, n);

const drop = (n: number) => <A>(xs: A[]) => xs.slice(n);
```

My preference is not to write types out that the compiler can figure out. Those few times I actually want to the full type of the symbol I just need to hover over it to know what TS inferred for the omitted types. But like I said this is just a preference your way is good too :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! It taught me some more things about the TypeScript type system. In retrospect your solution is actually quite obvious but I would not have thought of it before.
I actually started defining the function type before recently and I am also not sure yet if this is the way to go, but it is closer to the way it is done in Haskell and Purescript and I notice it makes it more readable to me. That might just be a silly reason and perhaps I will change it in the future but for now it works for me. I am open to suggestions though!